# Change Icon of Unchecked CheckBoxMenuItem

Tags: java, look-and-feel, nimbus

I'm trying to change the Icon of a CheckBoxMenuItem with the Nimbus Look&Feel.

```
    UIManager.put("CheckBoxMenuItem[Selected].checkIcon", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/packagename/images/unchecked-icon.png")));
```

This works fine for the selected Checkbox, but what is the state of an unselected Box?

Answer (score 0):

It works. Just had to use the right order!

```
UIManager.put("CheckBoxMenuItem.checkIcon", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/package/images/unchecked.png")));
UIManager.put("CheckBoxMenuItem[Selected].checkIcon", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/package/images/checked.png")));
```